# Marcar el primer radio button generado con un bucle en pug

Tags: html, pug

Estoy utilizando [pug](https://pugjs.org) para generar una lista de radio buttons usando un bucle `while`:

```
- var n = 0;
while n < 11
  input(type="radio", name="cb", id="cb"+n, value=n)
  label(for="cb"+n) #{n++}
```

El problema es que de este modo no se marca ninguno por defecto y quiero que el primero de ellos esté marcado por defecto y no sé cómo se haría.

De momento he sacado el primer elemento de la lista y lo he puesto fuera con un `checked=""` para que aparezca marcado por defecto:

```
input(type="radio", name="cb", checked="", id="cb0", value=0)
label(for="cb0") 0
- var n = 1;
while n < 11
  input(type="radio", name="cb", id="cb"+n, value=n)
  label(for="cb"+n) #{n++}
```

Pero, aunque funciona, esto parece poco eficiente porque estoy repitiendo código y, si quiero realizar cambios, tengo que hacerlo en dos sitios diferentes.

¿Existe algún modo de hacer que el primer radio button tenga ese atributo adicional sin necesidad de sacarlo fuera del bucle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede añadir un valor condicional para un atributo, así como quiero que el primero esté marcado y el bucle va desde 0 hasta 11, lo que habría que hacer es añadir una condición que compruebe si `n` es cero y asignarle ese valor al atributo `checked`.

Así queda el código al final

```
- var n = 0;
while n < 11
  input(type="radio", name="cb", id="cb"+n, value=n, checked=(n == 0))
  label(for="cb"+n) #{n++}
```